# Can I use Pydantic to deserialize a Union type, without creating another basemodel?

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I want to deserialize some data into a union type like so:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated, Union, Literal

class Foo(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["foo"] = "foo"
    x: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    type: Literal["bar"] = "bar"
    x: float


Baz = Annotated[Union[Foo, Bar], Field(discriminator="type")]


d = {
  "type": "bar",
  "x": 10.1
}


# Deserialize Baz here
```

This could be done by making another base model and deserializing it there, but I was wondering if there was a way to use a function within Pydantic to do it without this?

```py
class Config(BaseModel):
    baz: Baz


model = Config.model_validate({"baz": d})
print(model)  # Outputs: baz=Bar(type='bar', x=10.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pydantic.TypeAdapter`

```py
from pydantic import TypeAdapter

model = TypeAdapter(Baz).validate_python(d)
```